# Mortgage overpayment advice

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage

I've got a mortgage in the UK with a 5 year fixed rate of 1.69% that expires in Dec 2025 and started in May 2021. I've decided to pay it as soon as possible and I'm trying to figure out what's the most efficient way to do that. Every year I'm allowed to overpay 10% of the outstanding balance with the fees for overpaying on top of the 10% being 5% in the first year, 4% in the second, etc. Given that, I'll definitely be able to save more than 10% of the outstanding balance every year, should I overpay all my savings immediately and pay the penalties or should I put my savings over 10% in a savings account and pay them after the 5year product expires?

Just doing the math, if I overpay at the start of the 2nd year, I'd be saving around 4 years of interest  1.69^4=8.15, so in theory I should save 8.15%-4%=4.15% on the extra money I overpay. Following this logic however, it seems less worth overpaying extra after that (3rd year is 1.69^3-3=1.8%, 4th year - 1.69^2-2=1.38% and  5th year - 1.69-1=0.69%) since I might be able to find a savings account/invest in a low risk index fund and get a better return. Is that a correct assumption?

Also, every time I overpay, my monthly payment is reduced, so that the original term doesn't change. With that in mind, should I overpay regularly, e.g monthly, or save and pay in a lump sum at the end of each year? I can't figure out which would reduce the outstanding balance faster.

Comment: Follow the math!!

Comment: @RonJohn I think the question here is essentially "how do I *do* the math?"

Comment: *...that expires in Dec 2025* - what expires? The rate or the mortgage? Is the entire balance due at that point, or does the rate change (and if so, to what)?

Comment: You say the penalty for overpaying more than 10% is 5% in the first year, 4% in the second ... What does the percent reference? Presumably the overpayment limit means 10% of the balance at the beginning of the year (or end of prior year), rather than current balance (otherwise you'd never pay off the loan without paying penalties), but are the penalties based on the loan amount or overpayment amount?

Comment: @yoozer8 but he did the math.  At least it looks reasonable.  Also,

Comment: "every time I overpay, my monthly payment is reduced," - typically with a UK mortgage provider, a fee-free overpayment such as you describe can *at your choice* be used to either reduce term *or* reduce monthly payment. It will discuss this in your mortgage agreement

Comment: @yoozer8 UK mortgages are typically products structured as a short (1-5 year) term with some kind of rate certainty (a fix, a cap, a discount to the base rate, etc), followed by the remaining term of the mortgage on the lender's Standard Variable Rate (which is up to the lender's commercial choices, but typically floats some percentage points above the Bank of England base rate). Usual consumer behaviour is to be on such a deal then switch to a new one at the end of the product term. While on the SVR, there are (again typically) no penalties for overpayment.

Comment: Have you asked your mortgage provider? Notwithstanding what it says in the contract, there may be alternatives that they can offer, and there's nothing to lose by asking.

Comment: Do you expect to have ISA allowance available?

Comment: I think there is an important detail missing: how much of the principle you are paying off during the 5 years. Your math (1.69^4) seems only correct if you would not pay anything (and thus even pay compound interest) or at least not a lot (to be reasonable close). On the other hand, if your regular payments would be high enough to pay the full amount in 5 years, the total interest paid during those 5 years would be 4,3% of the original loan amount, so paying 5% fee seems unreasonable. (But I hope that your bank is not allowed to even offer this option if you would pay more.)

Comment: @Solarflare it's highly unlikely the mortgage will have a term of 5 years as well as a discount period of 5 years.  The term is more likely to be 20 or 25 years, sometimes more (when I looked, you couldn't get a 5 year fix on less than about an 18 year term)

Comment: (@AakashM but really more @ Stargazer) that's true for one-off repayments. You can also make monthly overpayments and those often can't go towards reducing the minimum monthly payment, only the term. I would have liked to do this as a way of putting money aside in good times to allow me to reduce my fixed outgoing if times get worse.

Comment: @ChrisH I used the 5 years as one side of the 2 extreme cases: if you pay absolutely nothing (e.g. not even the interest), you get to 1.69^4 (or 5), if you pay it all in 5 years, you get to 4,3% (or 2,8% if you remove interest for first year). This was just to show that it will indeed depend on the payment rate. The actual value will be somewhere in between, but since paying "interest only" would already be at 4*1,69=6,7%, the 5% fee might already be very close to what you would save (depending on payment rate).

Comment: @Solarflare I guess if your comment had been an answer (if you'd had enough information to write one) it would have been able to take into account more caveats, but it's an unrealistic example because the product wouldn't have been sold.  In particular your point in brackets at the end wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to analyse any given overpayment is by comparing it with the most similar possible alternative at the time.

Let's take your possible overpayment with 4 years left on the mortgage. Let's also assume you have some ISA allowance left.

For the 4 years until your mortgage fixed rate expires, you could take out a fixed rate ISA. That has exactly the same level of risk as the mortgage overpayment in that the return isn't dependent on any interest rate changes.

[Searching right now](https://moneyfacts.co.uk/isa/4-year-fixed-rate-isas/) I see rates of around 1.50% available. Your return on that money would be `

`(1.015)^4 - 1` ~= `0.061` = `6.1%`.

With the mortgage overpayment, you would lose 4% right away so your notional return is

`0.96*(1.0169)^4 - 1` ~= `0.027` = `2.7%`.

So if you have ISA allowance available, you have a clearly better alternative to the overpayment. That doesn't mean you should do that, maybe there's some better option than the fixed-rate ISA, but I would say you certainly shouldn't overpay.

If you don't have ISA allowance available, then you can still get a 4 year fixed rate account, but you might have to pay tax on any interest depending on a few factors like how much you earn and how much interest you get in total across all your savings. In fact it seems that the non-ISA fixed rates are significantly higher than the ISA fixed rates - currently [1.95% is available](https://moneyfacts.co.uk/savings-accounts/4-year-fixed-rate-bonds/) so it seems likely that even after tax you'd also be better off than the mortgage overpayment.

When you come to considering the overpayments in later years, you can do similar analyses based on the rates available at the time.

Comment: Savings rates (UK) must have improved quite a bit recently. When I last checked I couldn't do much better than about 1.2%, and that with hassles or for a longer fixed term than I wanted, so started making regular mortgage overpayments instead of regular additions to my savings.

Comment: @ChrisH interest rate expectations will be heading up quite a bit given increasing inflation

Comment: That's true. I'm not in a position to take out anything medium term for a little while, so was looking at instant access to 1 year, and that was a month or two ago